# Renaming a file from myFile.sh to myFile.bash?

Tags: macos, bash, sh

**PART 1**
Ok so i'm using Mac and I started out with a file called...

Example: `myFile.sh`

In Terminal I ran this file in its directory by typing...

```
bash myFile.sh
```

That works perfectly, but then I did some research about bash vs sh and found that I could have also written it like this...

```
sh myFile.sh
```

That also worked. I did some more research and an idea came to mind, that since bash is the "newer" way to do things, I thought I would try to rename `myFile.sh` to `myFile.bash` to see if it would still run in terminal if I typed this...

```
bash myFile.bash
```

And it worked perfectly! But now I'm wondering if there is a reason that the file was originally named `myFile.sh` instead of `myFile.bash`

So, is it bad that I renamed it to `myFile.bash` instead of `myFile.sh`? Or is it totally fine??

(i'm new to Terminal commands)

**PART 2**

Another question:
How would I make this "myFile.sh" executable? This is the contents of myFile.sh below:

```
#!/bin/bash 
python runtime/recompile.py "$@"
```

NOTE: I did some research and tried renaming myFile.sh to myFile.command which should make it executable when I open the file, but it didn't work and I got this error in Terminal:

```
python: can't open file 'runtime/recompile.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

So my questions really are:

a) How do I make myFile.sh executable in Terminal?
b) Why didn't renaming myFile.sh to myFile.command?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The `can't open file` message means simply that `runtime/recompile.py` doesn't exist.  That has nothing to do with the name of your `myFile.whatever` script.  But you probably don't need the shell script at all; just make sure your Python script has `#!/usr/bin/python`, run `chmod +x` on it, and run it directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is fine, it will work with different extensions and without extension as well. File extensions are meaningless in Unix (reference: http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/korn_shell.html). Extensions are useful for humans to identify files quickly.

You should probably use `.sh` extension as it is more popular and shorter than `.bash`.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably make those files executable using `chmod +x filename` and specify the script interpreter in the first line (shebang):

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Or, to respect `$PATH`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

This way, the file itself specifies what script interpreter to use. You can even specify arguments to `bash` this way. If you require the configuration applied to login shells inyour script, you could do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash --login
```

---

Using a custom file extension such as `.bash` might break non-obvious processes, such as FTP file transfers if you are also using Windows systems: Many FTP programs treat files with specific extensions as text, changing the line endings. If you use non-standard file extensions for your scripts, this won't happen and `\r` (carriage return) characters from Windows will be retained.

---

Your renaming to `.command` probably does not work, since your working directory changed along with how you execute your file. It will always be executed in `$HOME`, e.g. `/Users/danielbeck`, and relative paths need to start there. It's safer to provide an absolute path.

---

If you don't require a Terminal window for program execution, you can also use *Automator* and its *Run Shell Script* action to create an application or service, the latter with optional keyboard shortcut in *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts » Services*.

You need to configure the service to receive *files and folders in any application* as input, and execute it when having files selected; if it's an application, you can drag&drop files onto it. In any case, configure the *Run Shell Script* action to receive input *as arguments*.

Comment: Yeah, making it executable will be alot quicker than typing. Now, if I make it executable, does that mean I can just double click the file and it will work? Here is the code inside "myFile.sh": 

#!/bin/bash
python runtime/recompile.py "$@" 

(its for minecraft modding) in Terminal, what would I type to make it executable? NOTE: I tried renaming the extension from .sh to .command (it didnt execute when double clicked, there was an error), also would it be better to make it into a .app some how?? - or would that be pointless since making it executable would do the same thing*

Comment: @Jake Please edit your question, or post a new one, so you actually ask for what you want to accomplish. It appears this is a classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You probably need neither a bash script nor an executable file that launches python. Let me know once you've done it by commenting here, so I can post an answer.

Comment: Ok, I made a Part 2 to my question above.

Comment: @Jake "Multi-part" questions are generally frowned upon, as you're prone to sending us on a goose chase, and it's difficult to determine what user actually answered your question. The usefulness to others looking for an answer to a similar question is also very limited.

Answer (score 1):

The first line of an executable shell script should be a "[shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)"; the `#!` sequence is a "magic number" that tells the system that the rest of the line specifies an interpreter to which it will pass the name of your script.

For example, if you have a file named "foo" (no suffix needed) that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo This is foo
```

and you've run `chmod +x foo` (that's important!), then this:

```
./foo
```

is equivalent to this:

```
/bin/sh ./foo
```

and will produce the output `This is foo`.

You can call the script `foo.sh`, for example, if you want to emphasize that it's a shell script, but it's not necessary.  (Typically there's no reason for the user to care how it's implemented; in that case, you can just call it `foo`, which could be a shell script, a Perl or Python script, or a compiled executable.)

So what's the difference between `#!/bin/sh` and `#!/bin/bash`?  For most purposes, they're interchangeable.  `/bin/sh` is generally the Bourne Shell, which dates back to the early days of Unix; you'll find versions of it on all Unix-like systems, including Linux and MacOS.  `/bin/bash` is the GNU "Bourne-Again Shell", which includes the standard Bourne shell functionality plus a number of extensions.

If you use only features that are supported by the Bourne shell, it's probably better to use `#!/bin/sh` just as a matter of style, and to make it more likely that your script will run without change on other systems (which might not have Bash installed).

If you use Bash-specific features, you'll need to use `#!/bin/bash`.